# Algorithm for combination

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

I have designed an algorithm in java I generate all combinations of elements of a list . For example whereas the elements `[A, B , C]` it generates combinations , `[A]` , `[B]` , `[C]` , `[AB]` , `[BC]` , `[ABC]` . Or based on the elements `[A, A, B]` generates combinations `[A]` , `[B]` , `[AA]` , `[AB]` , `[AAB]` .
This is my code to generate combinations .

```
private List<Elemento> combinazioneMassima = new ArrayList<>();
    private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(Combinazioni3.class);

    public Combinazioni3(List<Elemento> generaCombinazioneMassima) {
        this.combinazioneMassima = generaCombinazioneMassima;
    }

    public void combine() {
        this.findAllCombinations(combinazioneMassima);
    }

    private static class Node{
        int lastIndex = 0;
    List<Elemento> currentList;
    public Node(int lastIndex, List<Elemento> list) {
            this.lastIndex = lastIndex;
            this.currentList = list;
    }
    public Node(Node n) {
            this.lastIndex = n.lastIndex;
            this.currentList = new ArrayList<Elemento>(n.currentList);
    }
    }

    public void findAllCombinations(List<Elemento> combinazioni) {
        Date dataInizio = new Date();
        List<List<Elemento>> resultList = new ArrayList<List<Elemento>>();
        LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
        int n = combinazioni.size();
        ArrayList<Elemento> temp = new ArrayList<Elemento>();
        temp.add(combinazioni.get(0));
        queue.add(new Node(0, temp));
        // add all different integers to the queue once.
        for(int i=1;i<n;++i) {
                if(combinazioni.get(i-1) == combinazioni.get(i)) continue;
                temp = new ArrayList<Elemento>();
                temp.add(combinazioni.get(i));
                queue.add(new Node(i, temp));
        }
        // do bfs until we have no elements
        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
                Node node = queue.remove();
                if(node.lastIndex+1 < n) {
                        Node newNode = new Node(node);
                        newNode.lastIndex = node.lastIndex+1;
                        newNode.currentList.add(combinazioni.get(node.lastIndex+1));
                        queue.add(newNode);
                }
                for(int i=node.lastIndex+2;i<n;++i) {
                        if(combinazioni.get(i-1) == combinazioni.get(i)) continue;
                        // create a copy and add extra integer
                        Node newNode = new Node(node);
                        newNode.lastIndex = i;
                        newNode.currentList.add(combinazioni.get(i));
                        queue.add(newNode);
                }
                GestoreRegole gestoreRegole = new GestoreRegole();
                gestoreRegole.esegui(node.currentList);
        }

    }
```

But however for `input > 250` the program stops and takes too long to make all combinations .
How can I improve this solution ? Or is there a better solution ?

Comment: Does it stop working or does it slow down? My first guess is that with > 250 elements in input you get a fairly large result that won't fit into you JVM. But it is just a guess until you provide some more information.

Comment: Hello,
unfortunately the program crashes and therefore does not calculate the final solution .

Comment: Could you provide the exception stack trace?

Comment: It is possible that it is using too much memory.

Comment: Surely it is too much use of memory, since during the execution of the program , checking the status of the RAM, it is used at 95% . That's why I wrote , with the hope that we can find a solution .

Comment: Useful read [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)...

Comment: Even if you think of faster algorithm in terms of time, the fact that you need to store all combinations will be problematic. Maybe you can return them one by one, according to some index that is to be assigned.

Comment: It could be a solution , but I can write Java code like this ?

Comment: Check my comment on  the answer bellow. I think is very simple to implement it.

Comment: Thank you so much , I replied below.

Answer (score 3):

For input=250, there will be so much combinations:
Look at this example:

```
(1) {a}     => {a}
(3) {a,b}   => {a}, {b}, {a,b}
(7) {a,b,c} => {a}, {b}, {c}, {a,b}, {a,c}, {b,c}, {a,b,c}
```

as you can see, there will be 2^n-1 elements

So for input=250 - 2^250-1 = [large number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E250-1) (1.8*10^75)

Too much memory is used. I think number about 20 (1048575) will make trouble too

Comment: I agree with you , unfortunately there is a very high consumption of memory . But what may be a solution ?

Comment: Solution is not to generate all, but step by step and proceed immediately, it wont use as much memory @pasq

Comment: And how I can proceed step by step ? Can you explain , using code ?

Comment: It is usable **only if you want to do something** with all combinations. Whenever one combination is created, call the method which requires all combinations, and then you can throw away this combination and save memory. @pasq

Comment: Just add an index variable which count the combinations one by one, you will then send a paramter n, to your method to get nth combination, when n == counter_of_combinations you return that one.

Comment: This thing already do in practice before adding it to the list of results , the combination step in GestoreRegole that filters the combination .

Comment: But you are storing every combination, that's why it crashes.

Comment: If you can leave me your email so you contact me and better explain your idea and codice.Grazie so much for your kindness

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic idea that I was telling you. I am inserting only the few key points. You should attach this to your code as you know best.

```
  public void findnThCombination(List<Elemento> combinazioni, int n) {
    ...
    int counter_combinations = 0; 
    // add all different integers to the queue once.
    for(int i=1;i<n;++i) {
            if(combinazioni.get(i-1) == combinazioni.get(i)) continue;
            temp = new ArrayList<Elemento>();
            temp.add(combinazioni.get(i));
            queue.add(new Node(i, temp));
    }
    counter_combinations ++;
    // do bfs until we have no elements
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
         //when you add a new combination
         counter_combinations++;
         if(counter_combinations == n) //return this combination
    }}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what int counter_combinations ?

Comment: It helps you know which combination are you generating so that you don't need to store them all, just get one by index(e.g. lexicographic).

Comment: Reading the code I have posted in the application , then at the end when I do if ( n == counter_combinations ) What should I write next?
The part of the same after I leave ?

Comment: In that case, you do whatever you need to do with the wanted combination(nth) and you return from the function, you don't go on.

Comment: I'm sorry I know I'm asking a lot , But not me you can write the code ? Because I can not understand how to do

Comment: I  am in exam session right now, so I don't have much time to dedicate to other stuff. But if I find, I will do it ;)

Comment: Thank you very much , if you want to leave you my email .

Comment: One thing I did not understand , this counter what is it ?